# Grayscale image segmentation using epanechnikov kernel

Tags: image

In the case of gray scale images, what to do if we get a decimal value like `65.5` as my convergence point in meanshift method?

How do we choose the window radius?

Comment: Context, please? What program / programming language are you talking about?

Comment: Its not about the program ....I'm trying to understand an algorithm that gets us a segmented image by means of mean shift method.....

Comment: It includes image data cluster analysis using meanshift method...In gray scale image pixels can take only non negative integer values from 0 to 255,  I wanted to know what do we do when we get a decimal values when we perform meanshift operation...

Comment: Uh. Round it, probably.